# Mystery in visited and unvisited links

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, pseudo-class

My question is very short.

For what reason text-decoration was removed from both visited and unvisited links, but red color applied only to unvisited link?

I.e. why these properties treated differently?

Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

```html
<p><a href="http://goooooooogle.com">Don't click it, so it should stay unvisited</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Click it, to make it visited</a></p>

<style>
  a:link {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: some specifity i guess .. visited is more specific than link (LoVe, HAte) https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/link-pseudo-classes-in-order/

Comment: Please ensure this isn't an issue because you are linking to #

Comment: @vandijkstef `#` is not an issue. Change it to normal google.com and click it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike `color`, `text-decoration` is not among the list of properties that can be changed with the `:visited` pseudo-class (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector#Limits_to_visited_link_styles)).

This results in visited links using the same text decorations that are applied to unvisited links. You cannot work around this.

Comment: but it's about color here

Comment: @Temani Afif: It's about both. The question is asking why they're treated differently.

Comment: euh sorry but no i didn't get it finally .. well let's forget about text-decoration and consider only color. In his case he colored :link and only the unvisited was colored red and the :visited remain with initial color ... and you said that we can use color with visited, so it's not a specifity issue like i answered ?? as visited is more specific or maybe :link doesn't target :visited ? or am completely out :s

Comment: @Temani Afif: Yes, it's not a specificity issue. There are no competing or overriding rules involved, since the question isn't asking about `a`, it's asking about `a:link` and `a:visited`, which do not override each other (MDN somehow manages to *contradict itself* on this). Basically, :visited only allows setting specific properties, and disallowed properties are instead taken from :link ("inherited" in some sense, but of course we're not talking about CSS inheritance here).

Comment: @BoltClock Probably, it could be added information about mutual exclusiveness of `:link` and `:visited` and incorrectness of MDN information, as you stated below Dippas's post. I made a draft here: https://jsfiddle.net/rd6yepdg/

Comment: ok ok i get it ... so since we cannot change text-decoration to visited they get it from :link and since we can use color so :visited don't get color of link and keep it's own one, right ?